# ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

Tags: python, docker, flask, heroku, cmake

While using docker build -t /flask-docker to create an image to later upload it to heroku, I get the following errors:

```
#8 417.3   ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
#8 417.3
#8 417.3   ----------------------------------------
#8 417.3   ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
#8 417.3   Running setup.py clean for dlib
#8 417.8 Successfully built audioread collection face-recognition-models imutils resampy termcolor wrapt
#8 417.8 Failed to build dlib
#8 418.8 Installing collected packages: urllib3, pyasn1, idna, chardet, certifi, zipp, typing-extensions, six, rsa, requests, pyasn1-modules, oauthlib, cachetools, requests-oauthlib, pyparsing, pycparser, numpy, llvmlite, importlib-metadata, google-auth, dataclasses, Werkzeug, threadpoolctl, tensorboard-plugin-wit, tensorboard-data-server, scipy, protobuf, packaging, numba, MarkupSafe, Markdown, joblib, grpcio, google-auth-oauthlib, cffi, cached-property, appdirs, absl-py, wrapt, tqdm, termcolor, tensorflow-estimator, tensorboard, SoundFile, scikit-learn, resampy, regex, pytz, python-dateutil, pooch, Pillow, opt-einsum, Keras-Preprocessing, keras-nightly, Jinja2, itsdangerous, h5py, google-pasta, gast, flatbuffers, face-recognition-models, dlib, decorator, click, audioread, astunparse, wincertstore, waitress, tensorflow, pandas, opencv-python-headless, nltk, librosa, imutils, gunicorn, Flask, face-recognition, colorama, collection, cmake
#8 464.8     Running setup.py install for dlib: started
#8 466.5     Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
#8 466.5     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#8 466.5      command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f582pi1r/dlib_8d153cd287b84149b3470adfe644cdd4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f582pi1r/dlib_8d153cd287b84149b3470adfe644cdd4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-93izef49/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6m/dlib
#8 466.5          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-f582pi1r/dlib_8d153cd287b84149b3470adfe644cdd4/
#8 466.5     Complete output (8 lines):
#8 466.5     running install
#8 466.5     running build
#8 466.5     running build_py
#8 466.5     package init file 'tools/python/dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
#8 466.5     running build_ext
#8 466.5
#8 466.5     ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
#8 466.5
#8 466.5     ----------------------------------------
#8 466.5 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f582pi1r/dlib_8d153cd287b84149b3470adfe644cdd4/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f582pi1r/dlib_8d153cd287b84149b3470adfe644cdd4/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-93izef49/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.6m/dlib Check the logs for full command output.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

This is my Dockerfile setup:

```
FROM python:3.6.13

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python app.py"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might need to do `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake` before the `pip install`.

Comment: I was able to get through this error. Appreciate the help. I get this error when try to run it by using :
**docker run -it -p 2000:5000 <username>/flask-docker**

_docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python app.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown._

Comment: You want `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]` instead of what you have now.

Comment: You are a genius, that fixed that problem and I am able to run it to test it before deployment. One library I get an error with once it's running its soundfile which is included in the requiremnets.txt file. I get this error **OSError: sndfile library not found**
Do I need to do the same as with the cmake as you advised above with this library?

Comment: The error is after trying some functionalities within the app

Comment: Probably `apt-get install -y libsndfile`.

Comment: This was a great help. Everythinig is working great now as far as no errors. The last error I get while pushing the app to heroku is that is timing out. ---> remote:   Building wheel for dlib (setup.py): still running...
remote: =!= Build failed due to an error:
remote:
remote: =!= Timed out compiling app